# Optimize AppendRow operation in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I was experimenting append-only operation via Entity Framework.

Routed `Database.Log` to `Trace.Write`.

Consider a table as follows.

```
public class AzureBillingTest
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Team { get; set; }
}
```

The following code:

```
dbContext.Entry(value).State = EntityState.Added;
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

translates to something like:

```
INSERT [dbo].[AzureBillingTests]([Name], [Team])
VALUES (@0, @1)
SELECT [Id]
FROM [dbo].[AzureBillingTests]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [Id] = scope_identity()
-- @0: '175fb5c4cfa4474f8944ecec6f158fbb' (Type = String, Size = -1)
-- @1: 'billing' (Type = String, Size = -1)
-- Executing at 11/26/2015 11:45:21 AM -08:00
-- Completed in 182 ms with result: SqlDataReader
```

I think I know why we have SELECT statement for [Id] - for loading into Entity objects. Correct me if wrong?

Say, I don't want to load [Id] back into Entity Framework to optimize the query, what should I do?

Comment: Optimize only if you see a performance issue. At this time this query doesn't cause performance issue. If you want to don't get back your Id just make it a Guid and generate a new one every taime you create a new entity in your application.

Comment: Hmm, guid may not work to me. There is definitely a performance issue in case of extremely large tables :/ which I use.